# Property delegate must have a 'getValue(InventoryApplication, KProperty&lt;*&gt;)' method. None of the following functions is suitable:

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I stuck at this problem

```
class InventoryApplication : Application() {

    val database: ItemDatabase by lazy { ItemDatabase.getDatabase(this) }

}
```

Error class
[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8E4M.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i was able to resolve it by going to the `ItemRoomDatabase.kt` file, change the INSTANCE variable in the companion object, to return a non-null type `ItemRoomDatabase`? and the `getDataBase()` function to return a type `ItemRoomDatabase`, rather than a `RoomDatabase` return type as requested in the codelab example.

Your final code in the `ItemRoomDatabase.kt` file should look something like this:

```
@Database(entities = [Item::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ItemRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun itemDao(): ItemDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ItemRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): ItemRoomDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    ItemRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "item_database"
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()

                INSTANCE = instance

                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```